# Semisimplicity of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am being asked to figure out when $\mathbb Z_n$ is a semisimple ring. It is clear to me that if $n$ is prime then $\mathbb Z_n$ is simple, which implies it is semisimple.

If $n=p_1...p_n$ is a product of primes all having power $1$ (in other words, $p_i \neq p_j$ when $i \neq j$) then each $\mathbb Z_{p_i}$ is simple as $\mathbb Z$-module and by the chinese remainder theorem $$\mathbb Z_n=\mathbb Z_{p_1} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z_{p_n}$$ where the member of the right is a direct sum of simple rings. However, it is not so clear to me whether if each $\mathbb Z_{p_i}$ is a submodule of $\mathbb Z_n$, so I don't know if I could conclude that $\mathbb Z_n$. I would like some help with this case and to consider if there is another possibility for $\mathbb Z_n$to be semisimple (if not, how could I prove these are the only two cases?).

Comment: How can you check if the summands are submodules?

Comment: Well, there is a correspondence between "subgroups of $\mathbb Z/\langle n\mathbb Z \rangle=\mathbb Z_n$ and "subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, $m \mathbb Z$ : $n\mathbb Z \subset m\mathbb Z$", and $n\mathbb Z \subset m\mathbb Z$ if and only if $m$ divides $n$, which happens to be the case for any prime in the prime factorization of $n$, so at least we have that all of those summands are subgroups of $\mathbb Z_n$. It is easy to check closure by the action of $\mathbb Z$. Am I correct?

Comment: I mean, the conclusion would be that all the summands are submodules of $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: I mean, what do you need to check to see whether those summands are $\mathbb Z_n$-sumodules? (I am merely asking for the definition!)

Comment: Oh, I have to check that the summands are subgroups of $\mathbb Z_n$ and also that they are close by the action of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$ (I've said by the action of $\mathbb Z$ before but it's wrong, we are seeing $\mathbb Z_n$ as a module over itself).

Comment: Well, to do that you have to be prcise about *what* subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$ you are writing $\mathbb Z_{p_1}$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that the Jacobson radical of a semisimple ring is zero?

If so, you can easily show that $n$ would have to be a squarefree positive integer for $\Bbb Z_n$ to have Jacobson radical zero.

You've already mentioned you have the converse that $\Bbb Z_n$ is a product of fields for a squarefree integer, so then you would have both directions.